# Why do we use this "Post::model()" in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii so I don't know much, but I can tell that Post is the name of my Model class.

The following code contains this `$models = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);`

Comment: its a static call in php to a class named Post with a function / method named model.  Its like `$Post->model()` but without an instance ( obj ) variable for the class.

Comment: I don't have a method named model() anywhere.

Comment: so no `coach::model()` method?  lol.  I'd wager the class `Post` does.  PHP 101   http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/php/Static_Methods.html  Nothing to do with Yii, either it has that method or it has `__callStatic()`  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: sorry u were right...my model does have model method....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You class Post  is a CActiveRecord class and in this class there is a 
model method

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#model-detail

> ```
> model()   Returns the static model of the specified AR class. CActiveRecord
> ```

Returns the static model of the specified AR class. The model returned is a static instance of the AR class. It is provided for invoking class-level methods (something similar to static class methods.)

Answer (score 1):

Hii this method is written in your model. In your case it is in Post model and if you want to know more than it written in your yiilite.php file under your framework folder.

For more info read this

http://www.yiiframew...rd#model-detail

The static model returned by model() contains the db schema meta data regarding the class.
So we need to call model() to get the static model when we call the functions like find() and findAll().